# Color framed text in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

What approach can be taken, if not built in anyway, to frame the text of a TextBlock with a color? For instance white text with black borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the text to a geometry

A Geometry can be drawn using a Stroke (outline) and a Fill (inner brush)

[See this page for examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745816.aspx)